# How to config AWS EMR to wait for while after last job finished

Tags: amazon-emr

Currently EMR cluster would automatically terminated after last job was finished.
We have service would send new job(step) to existing running EMR cluster.
Since cluster launching take time and cost
What we want is to let EMR cluster waiting for 5 minutes once last job is done, so service could still looking for this running cluster instead to init a new once.

Anyone knows if that possible and how to config?

Thanks

Google and have not find exactly answer online.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [auto-termination policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-AutoTerminationPolicy) with an idle timeout. Be aware about [the conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-auto-termination-policy.html) that EMR uses to determine if a cluster *is* idle though.

You can set the timeout using the `RunJobFlow.AutoTerminationPolicy.IdleTimeout` property. The EMR will use a set of conditions to check if the cluster is idle, and if the conditions are satisfied for the period that you specified, EMR terminates the cluster. For example, one of the conditions is that HDFS utilisation, the storage used, must be below 10%. That means that if the applications use HDFS, they or a separate step may need to clean up the space for EMR to consider the cluster as idle. For the full and up to date set of conditions, please refer to page [Using an auto-termination policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-auto-termination-policy.html).

Also, please see page [Control cluster termination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-termination.html) and [StepConfig. ActionOnFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_StepConfig.html) property for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I use SDK 2.15.51, but in `RunJobFlowRequest`, I did not find AutoTerminationPolicy attribute I can setup it. Do you know how to setup it when runJobFlow()?

Comment: I changed to latest SDK version, found hey have that attribute.
but after I submit job, the console shows:

Termination option
Automatically terminate cluster after last step ends
Idle time
5 minutes

RunJobFlowRequest
            .builder()
            .autoTerminationPolicy(
              AutoTerminationPolicy
                  .builder()
                  .idleTimeout(300)
                  .build()
            )

Comment: Isn’t that what you wanted?

Comment: Apparently, you may need to additionally set keepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps to true. Please see [EMR keepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps incorrectly defaults to false](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/605) AWS SDK issue.